# Serving HTML 5 Video From Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS)

Tags: html, video, sharepoint-2007

I want to server HTLM 5 video clips from Sharepoint 2007. The clips will be relative small in size (<1MByte). I've developed a Custom WebPart which generates de HTML 5 tags and can be configured to either use a URL to a link clip or either a document library.

The problem I've found is that when the content is stored in a document library the video cannot be processed by the browser. Using Firefox 3.6 I obtain a gray box. If I store the video file in the filesystem (inside moss virtual directory), the video is shown ok.

Using firebug, I've seen that when the video is stored in the filesystem, the Content-Type is correct (It's the one I've stup in IIS registering the MIME type), and also the content is served chunked (I see lots of 206 responses).

When the content is stored in a document library, the Content-Type is set to HTML, and I only see a 200 (OK) Response.

Any ideas if this kind of content can be served via a document library ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off with the files on the filesystem. When the SharePoint Product Team posted about [the Podcasting Kit for SharePoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=530), they didn't list this as a reason, but they did decide to store the videos on the file system instead of a document library. I think that's a pretty good indicator of the level of the problem you are dealing with.